# jquery $.ajax vs $.when async multiple tasks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following structure:

```
[input=text]    ||    [select=field]    ||    [button]

   John                  London                Press
```

After the button being pressed this is what happens:

```
[input=text]    ||    [select=field]    ||    [button]

  John                  London                AjaxLoad.gif
  Maria                 New York                Press
```

So on..

```
[input=text]    ||    [select=field]    ||    [button]

  John                  London                AjaxLoad.gif
  Maria                 New York              AjaxLoad.gif
  Alfredo               Lisbon                  Press
```

When the button is pressed an ajax function is executed and a gif of ajaxload remains in that line until it returns the result from the ajax. The problem is, it's done 1 by 1 and not all at the same time.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "addFields.php",
  data: {name: name, category: category},
  async: true,
  success: function(data){
      $(field_id).html(data);
  }
});
```

I have googled a bit and I found I could use `$.when` and it might fill my needs..but unfortunatelly it's actually the same as the `$.ajax`. It only executes 1 by 1 and not all at the same time.

```
$.when(
    $.get("addFields.php", {name: name, category: category}, function(data){
        info = data;
    })
).done(function(){
    $(field_id).html(info)
});
```

Am I doing something wrong or this should work?

**Edit (1):** [Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rju5j/2/) so you guys can have a better view of what I'm doing. As you can see it's all dynamic and there's no limit of lines.

Comment: What's the problem here?  I don't understand the question.  What *exactly* are you trying to do?  What do you mean by " it's done 1 by 1 and not all at the same time"?  *What* do you want to run "all at the same time"?  Why are you using `async: true`?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, info is just a variable, obviously defined before..no big deal for the problem.

Comment: @RocketHazmat the problem, as I said in the topic, is that this executes 1 by 1, which means, when button is pressed it only executes the function IF and only IF the previous function is completed.
Edited: and I'm looking for a way of executing the same function at the same time in several buttons pressed.

Comment: The success callback is called when the ajax is made with no errors and $.when is waiting for the promise returned from $.get to be resolved, `async:true` is the default value of the ajax calls

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't get what you're trying to do, both of the ajax calls at the same time ? do the two ajax calls and then do something?

Comment: My answer pretty much explains it...

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie probably the problem is the limits of numbers of parallel ajax calls..see my edited post.

Comment: I have been rewriting/simplifying your code to better understand it, but without a dummy service in place it is difficult to see the problem. Do you have any way of publishing your php somewhere the JSFiddle can see it?

Comment: Here is an updated JSFiddle. Hope it helps you or anyone else explain or solve the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Rju5j/5/

Comment: I looked at your jsfiddle code and I can't see where this should allow me to have multiple tasks running the same function?